# What is the impact of leaked question paper on exam result?

Tags: presentation

I would like to know if an exam is taken place on a leaked question paper that is some students got the question paper prior to the exam would it have any impact on the result of the exam?

Can you name a few [websites] where can I get devices to prevent cheating in the exam? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, No, Maybe...

Comment: I do not understand the question... Are you a lecturer and think that some students might have had access to the exam questions? Then yes, that will definitely affect the result of the exam, and the way to prevent cheating is to make new exam questions and make sure that they are not leaked...

Answer (score 3):

1. Of course it will have an impact. It depends on the format of the exam, but people can get external help, check their results with a private tutor or have them do the exam for them. At the very least, they will know what is on the test, so they know what to revise and what to skip. It seems a no-brainer that people who saw the test one day early will have an advantage with respect to those who didn't.
2. Not sure what you mean by 'cheating' here, and what kind of devices you have in mind. There is no website in the world that would prevent you from 'leaking' a question paper, if it happens away from the keyboard. Similarly, there is no website that would prevent students from speaking to each other, exchange written leaflets with the answers, take out their notes while you don't watch, check their cellphone. You need physical security and supervision to prevent that.